# Use sprintf - query size first or pass a MAX_PATH large array

Tags: c++, c, string, printf

I am implementing a helper function that will use sprintf by a given format and return as a string. I am not sure whether it will be slower if I query the needed size first then pass the allocated buffer into sprintf.

```
wchar_t buf[MAX_PATH] = {};
swprintf(buf, MAX_PATH, format, ...);
```

vs

```
int cchBuf = swprintf(0, 0, format, ...);
unique_ptr<wchar_t[]> buf (new wchar_t[cchBuf+1]);
swprintf(buf.get(), cchBuf, format, ...);
```

Answer (score 2):

According to this [reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cwchar/swprintf/) swprintf() will return a negative value if the converted string doesn't fit in *len* characters. No where does it say that you can pass zero and get the functionality you're looking for. The [reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/snprintf/) for snprintf() says something different, which is maybe where you've got this idea from.

This [alternate reference](http://linux.die.net/man/3/swprintf) for swprintf() is also fairly clear on the point,

"*swprintf() and vswprintf() take a maxlen argument, sprintf(3) and vsprintf(3) do not. (snprintf(3) and vsnprintf(3) take a maxlen argument, but these functions do not return -1 upon buffer overflow on Linux.)*".

It's saying that snprintf() does not return -1 upon buffer overflow, implying that swprintf() does.

So I'm fairly sure that your second code fragment won't work as intended, or at least won't be portable.

A better approach might be to over allocate the buffer initially, call swprintf(), then trim the buffer to the right length afterwards. This will involve about the same amount of runtime as calling swprintf() twice, and will work. Better still you could have a static working buffer inside your helper function for swprintf() to work into, then allocate an ideal sized results buffer and copy the result into it. Again that's about the same amount of runtime.

Comment: You'd think the much-needed "measure-first-then-allocate" behavior of `sprintf` et.al. would have been standardized by now. The lack of consensus really make these APIs suitable only for making security holes...

Comment: @defube, indeed, but at least it keeps us on our toes and feeling wary. A language with all these little traps is exciting!

Answer (score 0):

If you are fine with the output being constrained to `MAX_PATH` characters, the first example will work.

The performance of the second example depends on the runtime, though it will be slower than the first due to requiring 2 library calls and an allocation. However, it is the more robust option.